# How to choose Android plugin version? [UNSUPPORTED VERSION issue]

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to programming so this question might sound trivial.
I am getting "Unsupported Android Plugin version: 3.6.4." so I should change the version of the Android Plugin. But how should I choose the correct version?

I am running Flutter version 3.7.7. and the version of the Android gradle plugin that I have specified in the dependencies is 3.6.4.